# Need help trying to make Cmake find third party libraries

Tags: c++, integration, cmake, zlib, taglib

I currently have a project that links to two third party libraries. These libraries have to be built by themselves and then linked to the project. One is taglib and the other is zlib. I noticed that when you use the Cmake-gui program on the taglib directory you're required to specify where zlib has been built and installed.

My goal is to get CMake to do a similar thing for my program. Since the place these libraries are stored will be inconsistent how can I prompt the user to provide the path to the libraries required?

I hope this is specific enough.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the case of ZLib, a FindZLIB.cmake is provided with CMake and you can "simply" put a [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:find_package) call in your cmakelists. If necessary you can make some modifications to findzlib.cmake to suit your needs. E.g. adding ZLIB_DIR as an additional hint when searching for the library. This ZLIB_DIR can then be set by the user.

Assuming your library/executable is called YourProject, you can use it as follows.

```
find_package( ZLIB REQUIRED )
if ( ZLIB_FOUND )
    include_directories( ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
    target_link_libraries( YourProject ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} )
endif( ZLIB_FOUND )
```

You should use the same approach for TagLib, but instead should write your own FindTagLib.cmake (or search for a good one).

The important part here is that you give the user the option to set a TagLib_DIR variable, which you use to search for TagLib and that you use [FindPackageHandleStandardArgs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#module%3aFindPackageHandleStandardArgs) to report success or failure.

Comment: So all I do is put this FindTaglib.cmake in the same directory as the CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: It searches for FindTagLib.cmake in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH. I am not sure if the main dir with CMakeLists.txt is already in there. If not you can add it: set( CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about interactive prompt, but you always can use environment variables or following:

```
cmake -D<VAR_NAME>:STRING=<path to custom zlib> .
```

to provide cmake with custom zlib or taglib location.

Don't forget to update FindZLIB.cmake to handle this variables in FIND_PATH and FIND_LIBRARY