trying to build podofo 0.9.8 on mingw64, missing zlib
I can't install podofo version 0.9.8 (clone from git https://aur.archlinux.org/podofo-0.9.git), because I get this error of ZLIB
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:233 (message):
  Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:603 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/FindZLIB.cmake:47 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:306 (FIND_PACKAGE)

but I have
 $ echo ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/

 $ echo ${ZLIB_LIBRARY} 
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/zlib1.dll

Can somebody help me please?
Thanks in advance
UPDATE:
I added to cmake the parameters -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR="C:/msys64/mingw64/include"
and -DZLIB_LIBRARY="C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/zlib1.dll"
in the PKGBUILD file, and now is missing only the ZLIB_LIBRARY...the command line with the output is this:
$ makepkg -sri
==> Making package: podofo-0.9 0.9.8-3 (Tue Jul 16 09:23:38 2024)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Found podofo-0.9.8.tar.gz
  -> Found 23d26f39.patch
==> Validating source files with sha256sums...
    podofo-0.9.8.tar.gz ... Passed
    23d26f39.patch ... Passed
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Extracting podofo-0.9.8.tar.gz with bsdtar
==> Starting prepare()...
patching file CMakeLists.txt
patching file src/podofo/CMakeLists.txt
patching file src/podofo/libpodofo.pc.in
==> Removing existing $pkgdir/ directory...
==> Starting build()...
Will install libraries to /usr/lib/podofo-0.9
Using gcc specific compiler options
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:233 (message):
  Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:603 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/FindZLIB.cmake:47 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:306 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...


ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR and ZLIB_LIBRARY should be cmake variables passed through -D command line parameters, they are not environment variables.

Related or dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6174604/4165552 depends if find_package(ZLIB) is your only problem. But since it looks like you are stuck with windows, most likely you just need to hint the CMake about libs location.

Thanks! I added to cmake -DZLIB_LIBRARY="C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/zlib1.dll" and -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR="C:/msys64/mingw64/include"...but now is telling me is missing only  ZLIB_LIBRARY, I can't understand

Please, update your question post with the exact command line of calling cmake.

The library should be .lib, an import library, not .dll.

@3CxEZiVlQ I'm on mingw64 (windows), I have only the dll

https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib has the import library /mingw64/lib/libz.dll.a and the static library /mingw64/lib/libz.a

Building zlib from source is quite trivial. You could try that.

Note that the latest podofo version is 0.10.3, see: https://github.com/podofo/podofo
